# Thumbnails not showing up after creating a post via linkedin API call

Tags: linkedin-api

Thumbnails from external urls are not loading. However, the [post inspector tool](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect/https:%2F%2Fwww.cnbc.com%2F2022%2F10%2F28%2Fmore-than-40percent-of-us-households-will-owe-no-federal-income-tax-for-2022.html) loads it just fine.

Page I used to perform some tests: https://www.cnbc.com/2022/10/28/more-than-40percent-of-us-households-will-owe-no-federal-income-tax-for-2022.html

Things I've tried so far:

1. Add an extra parameter at the end of the url in order to clear linkedin cache.
2. Post Inspector Tool
3. I did some research but I wasn't successful on finding a solution.
4. I created a post using different links like youtube and stackoverflow. Thumbnails didn't show up either.
5. I made sure each page has those required meta(open graph) tags that allows the crawler to retrieve information.

Here's an example of one of those API requests I've been calling to(I got this from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/share-on-linkedin)):

`

```
{
    "author": "urn:li:person:{ID}",
    "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
    "specificContent": {
        "com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent": {
            "shareCommentary": {
                "text": "Learning more about LinkedIn by reading the LinkedIn Blog!"
            },
            "shareMediaCategory": "ARTICLE",
            "media": [
                {
                    "status": "READY",
                    "description": {
                        "text": "Official LinkedIn Blog - Your source for insights and information about LinkedIn."
                    },
                    "originalUrl": "https://www.cnbc.com/2022/10/28/more-than-40percent-of-us-households-will-owe-no-federal-income-tax-for-2022.html",
                    "title": {
                        "text": "Official LinkedIn Blog"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "visibility": {
        "com.linkedin.ugc.MemberNetworkVisibility": "PUBLIC"
    }
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

In the [Share Media](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/share-on-linkedin#share-media) object, you're missing the `media` attribute. It accepts LinkedIn URN so you'll need to upload the image. Personally, I'm not using that attribute but `thumbnails` that accepts image url. I don't see it in the docs anymore so something might have been changed. At least it's still working for me and I haven't seen it deprecated in the changelog yet. Be careful with the image requirements as well. It accepts an image url with this signature

```
{
      ...,
      "thumbnails": [{
        "url": "https://image-url.com"
      }]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The thing is, the thumbnail should be collected from the given url by linkedin but it's not resolving.